# Count occurences in a list of dataframes and store results in a new dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, count

I have a list of around 80 data frames in the following format:

```
myTable1 <- "ID    GROUP 
     1     5     
     2     5         
     3     4.9        
     4     4.9   
     5     4.9   
     6     2.0"
Data <- read.table(text=myTable1, header = TRUE)

myTable2 <- "ID     GROUP
     1      4.9
     2      4.8
     3      4.6
     4      4.6
     5      4.6"
Data <- read.table(text=myTable2, header = TRUE)
```

The data comes from different .csv files. And the do not have headers. I store the paths to them in a list called file_names and read the files like this:

```
data_list <- lapply(file_names, read.csv , header=FALSE, sep=",")
```

To add the headers I use:

```
data_list <- lapply(df, function(df) {colnames(df) <-c("ID", "Group"); df})
```

Each dataframe can contain different items in the column "Group", for example myTable2 does not contain an item in "Group" with the value 2.0 or 5. The columns may not have the same length.

What I want, is to count the occurrences of every item in the column "Group" of each file. To compare the number of occurrences the data should be stored in a separate dataframe in the following format:

```
Group   Table 1  Table 2
  5        2        0
 4.9       3        1
 4.8       0        1   
 4.7       0        0
 4.6       0        1
 2.0       1        0
```

Comment: Instead of `read.csv` withn `lapply` you can use a modified version that reads the file and stores the name of the file in a column. In this way you can group by both `GROUP` and file name to count and then reshape the dataset to get the format you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)

# function that reads file and stores name of file as a column
ReadFile = function(x) {read.csv(x) %>% mutate(id=x)}

# apply function to each file and combine as a dataframe
dt = list.files(pattern = "[.]csv$") %>% map_df(ReadFile)

dt %>%
  count(id, GROUP) %>%      # count file name and group
  spread(id, n, fill = 0)   # reshape

# # A tibble: 5 x 3
#   GROUP myTable1.csv myTable2.csv
#   <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>
# 1   2              1            0
# 2   4.6            0            3
# 3   4.8            0            1
# 4   4.9            3            1
# 5   5              2            0
```

Comment: I am a bit confused by your solutions, how is it able to read the files. At what place do I have to add the path to the files?

Comment: `list.files(pattern = "[.]csv$")` will create a vector of all file names in your workspace that end in "csv". Then the `map_df(ReadFile)` will apply that function to all those file names. `map_df` will work similarly to your `lapply` approach.

Comment: Can't I just use my existing list of file names, I forgot to describe it more detailed in my question. I create them with `file_names <- c(
  "~/path/to/myTable1.csv","~/path/to/myTable2.csv")`

Comment: I think you can, but probably you'll have longer names. Try to do this: `dt = file_names %>% map_df(ReadFile)` and see what you get.

Comment: Okay, I needed awhile to install tidyverse, but it seems that it works now. Now I have the problem that my data in the .csv files do not have headers, forgot about that. I tried to add them with `dt <- lapply(dt, function(dt) {colnames(dt) <- c("ID","Group");dt}}`but without success. Error: attempt to set colnames on an object with less than two dimensions

Comment: Change your function to this `ReadFile = function(x) {read.csv(x, header = F, col.names = c("ID","GROUP")) %>% mutate(id=x)}`

Comment: I can see the results in the console, but how do I store them in a separate dataframe, so I can plot it later?

Comment: `dt2 = dt %>% ...`